# Turn a datetime into days in python

Tags: python, datetime, days

I want to take in a string that is a date (ex. "2002-3-14") and turn it into total days since January 1st 1 AD (ex. 730,924).  How would I do this in python 2.7?  Is there a way to convert the datetime to a timedelta?

Comment: turn it into days? be more spesific please.

Comment: since January 1st 0000 AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

d0 = datetime.datetime.strptime("0001-1-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
df = datetime.datetime.strptime("2002-3-14", "%Y-%m-%d")

print(df-d0)

>> 730922 days, 0:00:00
```